# Filter XML with dynamic where clause

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<Events>
    <Event>
        <EventID displayName="Event ID">1</EventID>
        <EventName displayName="Event Name">Some event</EventName>
        <OrgID displayName="Organization ID">8</OrgID>
    </Event>
    <Event>
        <EventID displayName="Event ID">2</EventID>
        <EventName displayName="Event Name">Another Event</EventName>
        <OrgID displayName="Organization ID">10</OrgID>
    </Event>
</Events>
```

I want to be able to filter them by a where clause constructed dynamically. For example:

```
Where("Event ID = 2 AND (Organization ID = 8 OR Organization ID = 10)")
```

Please note that I can only use the displayName to filter the data. Obviously I can get the tag name from the displayName and construct the where clause, but that means some added calculations on the clients machine, which if possible, I'd like to avoid.

I have explored the options to use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) or [DataTable.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) but with my limited knowledge on Linq, I cant seem to find an easy way to adopt those to filter XML data. Any help/hint is appreciated.

Comment: why not parse the xml completely and store all the elements in a list..That way you would be able to filter out easily

Comment: Yes, currently thats what I am doing but this enables me to use a very limited filter criteria as opposed to what I really need. It does not to allow me to create the where clause at run-time depending on user input.

Answer (score 0):

So want you want to do is to use linq syntax to get data from your xml ?

Something like that?

```
XDocument loadedXML = XDocument.Load('Your xml file name');
var yourStrongTypeEventsList
   = (from event in loadedXML.Descendants("Event")
      where event.Element("EventID").Attribute("displayName").Value.Equals("Your value here")
      select new
         {                  
           EventID = event.Element("EventID").Value,
           EventName = event.Element("EventName").Value
         }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ-to-XML dot notation to extract the elements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string content = @"<Events>
    <Event>
        <EventID displayName=""Event ID"">1</EventID>
        <EventName displayName=""Event Name"">Some event</EventName>
        <OrgID displayName=""Organization ID"">8</OrgID>
    </Event>
    <Event>
        <EventID displayName=""Event ID"">2</EventID>
        <EventName displayName=""Event Name"">Another Event</EventName>
        <OrgID displayName=""Organization ID"">10</OrgID>
    </Event>
</Events>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(content));

            var events = doc.Descendants("Event")
            .Where(p => p.Elements("EventID").First().Value == "1")
            .Where(p => p.Elements("OrgID").First().Value == "8" || p.Elements("OrgID").First().Value == "10");
        }
    }
}
```

The System.XML.Linq namespace is incredibly useful.

Comment: I need to be able to construct the where clause dynamically as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the xml completely

```
var eventList=doc.Elements("Event")
                 .Select(x=>new 
                  {
                      EventId=int.Parse(x.Element("EventId").Value),
                      EventName=x.Element("EventName").Value,
                      OrgID=int.Parse(x.Element("OrgID").Value)
                  });
```

---

You could now make a generalized method,

```
public string getEventName(int eventId,params int[] orgId)
{
     return eventList.Where(x=>
                              x.EventId==eventId && 
                               orgId.Any(y=>y==x.OrgID))
                     .Select(x.EventName)
                     .Single();

}
```

Now you can do

```
getEventName(2);
getEventName(2,8);
getEventName(2,8,10);
```

Comment: Typesafe predicates wont work since I need to create the where clause dynamically. I dont know the exact filtering criteria, they are decided by the user.